# Constructing RegExp in JavaScript from object property (string)

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, regex

I am attempting to create a input directive in Angular which can be configured from a remote endpoint.

The object below should result in a input-field with `type=text` and should only be set to valid if the input is a 6-digit number.

```
{
    inputfield: {
        "name": "6-digit code",
        "type": "text",
        "pattern": "/^\d{6}$/"
    }
}
```

The problem I am encountering is that if I use `$setValidity` and check the value with a Regex generated from `pattern` I get the following:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^\d{6}$");

console.log(pattern.toString());
=> "/^d{6}$/"
```

Which is fine, as `\` is escaped as expected. I do have access to the endpoint delivering the data. This endpoint is a REST-endpoint written in Java. So at the endpoint the Regex is defined as follows:

```
String regex = "/^\\d{6}$/";
```

So, to sum up:

```
From endpoint: "/^\\d{6}$/"
Received at client: "/^\d{6}$/"
Constructing RegExp from the received object gives: "/^d{6}$/"
Wanted RegExp: /^\d{6}$/
```

Can this be achieved without declaring the Regex at the endpoint with quadrouple slashes (i.e. `"/^\\\\d{6}$/"`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The object below should result in a input-field with `type=text` and should only be set to valid if the input is a 6-digit number.
>
> ```
> {
>     "name": "6-digit code",
>     "type": "text",
>     "pattern": "/^\d{6}$/"
> }
> ```

In JavaScript, the source text `"/^\d{6}$/"` produces **exactly** the same string as `"/^d{6}$/"`. Since `\d` isn't a defined escape sequence, it's just `d` with an escape in front of it. In JavaScript, if a character doesn't need escaping but you escape it anyway, the escape is just ignored. (In contrast with JSON, which is strict and would complain about the text above.)

> So at the endpoint the Regex is defined as follows:
>
> ```
> String regex = "/^\\d{6}$/";
> ```

That means whatever is producing the JSON is doing so incorrectly, because if it were doing so correctly, the backslash before the `d` would be escaped and the source text of the object would look like this:

```
{
    "name": "6-digit code",
    "type": "text",
    "pattern": "/^\\d{6}$/"
}
```

...would work correctly with the `RegExp` constructor once (as [squint](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1106925/squint) pointed out in a now-deleted comment) you remove the leading and trailing slashes (otherwise, the regex will try to match `/` literally).

So the fix here is to fix whatever's producing the incorrect JSON, ideally by using a proper JSON library ([Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), ...).

Comment: Mistake from my side. The object that should define the inputfield is not JSON, but a JavaScript object received from a call to the REST endpoint. Sorry ;)

Comment: @oyvindym: It doesn't actually really matter, the fundamental problem remains that whatever is taking `String regex = "/^\\d{6}$/";`, putting it on an object as `pattern`, and then sending that object from server to client is doing so incorrectly. In JavaScript, the source text `"/^\d{6}$/"` defines **exactly** the same string as `"/^d{6}$/"` because unlike JSON, JavaScript is lenient and if you escape a character that doesn't need escaping (and the result isn't a defined escape sequence), the escape is ignored and just the character is used.